# Is it possible to use different repositories for resolution and deployment in Maven?

Tags: maven, artifactory

Is it possible to get the dependency artifacts from one Repository (PROD) and push the maven build output to another Repository (TEST)?
If YES, then what should be the configuration of POM and other settings?

Pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Nigam!

Of course, it's possible. In Maven, you configure the repositories you get the dependencies from in `settings.xml` `<repositories>` element - [here are the instructions](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories). You can specify any number of repositories there.

For deployment you use the `<distributionManagement>` element of your `pom.xml` and it can contain a repository different from ones you use for dependency resolution. [Here's the official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management).

If you use JFrog Artifactory (as the tag suggests), you can click on [the `Set Me Up` button](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Artifactory#UsingArtifactory-SetMeUp) on any Maven repository and get the instructions on configuring Artifactory repositories for resolution and deployment.